# Asp.net File upload

Tags: asp.net

Error - 
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.

Code in submit button

```
         protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
           FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/files/" +                   

            FileUpload1.FileName));

        }
           if (FileUpload2.HasFile)
              {
        FileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/files/" +   

                FileUpload2.FileName));

             }

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your content length in web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="51200" />
```

and:

```
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```